# how can we mix two mp3 files into one (i need mixing not concat)

Tags: php, ffmpeg, audio-recording

i have one mp3 file which have some blank spaces in that. Now i have another mp3 file which i want to insert into the spaces of the first mp3 file.

I am running with PHP, ffmpeg

Answer (score 0):

Just split one which have blank spaces into 3 parts, then join "first part" + "second file" + "third part" :)